# Why Php Media Gallery not working?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

I'm trying to create VIDEO/image gallery so it will make it easier for me to upload Videos/image to the gallery. 
The Gallery consists of a thumbnail image of videos/images, a one line description and when click the thumbnail is display image/video within a fancy box. I think so, it's basic. (The thumbnail and fancy box image are using the same image.) I'm new in Php and trying to implement this functionality to my current project as soon as possible.
I found something good here http://www.w3schools.in/php/media-gallery and I run it on my machine but got some issues listed below,
Any ideas? their is few issues with me,

1. Images are not display.
2. "From My Computer" and "From YouTube URL" links are not working.
3. YouTube icon not display on my YouTube video.
4. Theme and look not same as on demo.
5. fancy box interaction not working for me.

Php Code for index.php :

```
       <?php
            $result = $obj->getGalley();
            if (!empty($result)) {
                foreach ($result AS $row) {
                    /* IF is Video */
                    if ($row['media_type'] == 'YouTube') {
                        $rel = 'video';
                        $href = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" . $row['media_name'];
                        $src_bg = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $row['media_name'] . '/mqdefault.jpg';
                        $src = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $row['media_name'] . '/mqdefault.jpg';
                    } else {
                        /* IF is Image */
                        $rel = '';
                        $href = "images/large/" . $row['media_name'];
                        $src_bg = "images/small/" . $row['media_name'];
                        $src = "images/small/" . $row['media_name'];
                    }
                    ?>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-sm-4 gallery-block" data-media_guid="<?php echo $row['media_GUID']; ?>">
                        <div class="gallery-block-inner">  
                            <a class="photobox_a <?php if ($rel != '') { ?> media-video<?php } ?>" href="<?php echo $href; ?>" rel="<?php echo $rel; ?>" <?php if ($rel != '') { ?> style="background-image:url('images/placeholder.png'), url('<?php echo $src_bg; ?>');"<?php } ?>>
                                <img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" class="img-responsive">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <span class="media-name"><?php echo $row['media_name_original']; ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            } else {
                ?>
                <p id="gallery-empty">It's Empty</p>
                <?php
            }
         ?>
```

Upload Media code :

```
   <!-- Upload Media Starts -->
        <div class="row">
            <hr>
            <h3>ADD MORE MEDIA TO COLLECTION</h3>
            <div id="upload_button_group">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" id="upload_button">From My Computer</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button button-blue" id="upload_button_URL">From YouTube URL</a>
            </div>
            <form id="upload_form" name="upload_form" method="post" action="media_upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" id="upload_media" name="upload_media" accept="image/*" style="display:none">
            </form>
            <form id="upload_form_url" name="upload_form_url" method="post" action="media_upload.php"  style="display:none">
                <input class="text-field" name="youtube_url" id="youtube_url" type="text" placeholder="Please enter YouTube URL">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" id="upload_button_URL_save">Save</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button button-blue" id="upload_button_URL_cancel">Cancel</a>
            </form>
        </div>
   <!-- Upload Media Ends -->
```

Comment: All the code with demo is available on  http://www.w3schools.in/php/media-gallery. So, you can check their I just configure data base connection for my machine that's all. otherwise all code are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the code my best guess is that there are incorrect links and therefore browser cannot find those files. That explains missing images (1, 3?), css (4) and not working JavaScript (2,5).

Make sure that at localhost/path to your project/js/app.js can be found. This specifically controls the uploading. And for all other files that are there.

Comment: I used relative path like href="css/photobox.css" and also in my dreamweaver all linked files css, jquery as well as java script are displayes. So, I think all links are properly working. I don't know what the problem with code I debug it but, can't understand some code excepting html code.

Comment: Can you, please, look at the source code of the rendered website? In Firefox it's cmd/ctrl+u

Comment: Yes its the links are looks something different.

Comment: Now if you use that link there instead of current url, will you see an image? If yes then the links are working properly. Otherwise go to the directory with file manager and then adjust code accordingly

Comment: No not working any way ! when i use "script data-rocketsrc" then src is not like a source and the appropriate javascript is gone. its not linked with index.php. I think they can't provide proper code for download and other than html and php code remaining code unpredictable for me.

Comment: CSS and JavaScript works for me but images won't because I don't have the database they want set up.

Comment: OK @SarahGebauer thanks for your valuable views. So, i think i spend some time on it with a fresh mind. if it would runs in your machine (except database issues) then surely it also runs on my machine too.

Comment: So, when I render index.php page using firebug+F12 in firefox  All js file and css files are not rendered got "404 not found" even all links follows absolute path. So, I merge all js files and css files in same index page and all are working. I know its not a good way but solved my problem.